# One-to-many relationships. Attribute and Entity?

Tags: database-design

I may be misusing the word *attribute* here.

I am designing a database for a service-learning department.

I am confused about one-to-many relationships.
Suppose we have a relationship from **one A** to **many B**.
There seem to be one-to-many relationships, such as the one above, where the only information you need about the **A** is its name, and the list of entities associated with it.

I feel like I may be overthinking this, but I grasp the idea of how to deal with many-to-many relationships and not so much one-to-many relationships. I would appreciate some enlightenment on how to deal with these situations.

---

### Examples

**First example:**
A unique *Class* has only one *Semester* associated with it, but many Classes are offered in any Semester.

In the above example, should I have an entity table about Classes and include a column for Semester, or do I need to have an entity table for Semester and list the Classes that are offered each Semester?

**Another example:**
Each *Professor* is a part of one *Department*, and each Department is associated with many Professors.

So I wasn't including Department in the Professor entity table, and was rather planning on making a table that shows which Professors were in which Departments.
But I haven't seen much like that in any of my reading.

I hope my confusion is clear to an expert or any non-novice. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In regards to your class and semester problem, you may be looking for a cross-reference or mapping table.  (I may not be using the proper term, either!)

But imagine you have three tables:

```
SEMESTER
---------
ID (int)
Year (int)
Session (nvarchar)  -- values like 01, 02, 03 or Spring, Fall, etc.

CLASS
--------
ID (int)
Name (nvarchar)
Details (nvarchar)
...

SEMESTERCLASS
-------------
ID (int)
SemesterID (int)
ClassID (int)
```

So the SemesterClass table maps Semester to Class.  This way, your unique class can be part of multiple semesters and a semester can have multiple classes.

Hopefully this is what you're looking for.  Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

a many to many relationship is the same as two one to many relationships joining to one 'link table' (semesterclass in david's example). a lot of database software such as Oracle makes the 'link table' for you when you create the many to many relationship (they usually have unsightly names!)